# Nesting "and" statements with "or" statements

Tags: vba, excel

This line of my code gives me: Error 13: type mismatch
How do I combine an "nd" statent in an "or"?
ex: if a or b or c or (d and e) or (f and g)

Here is the code

```
If (cell.Value) = "FTV1" _
         Or (cell.Value) = "FTV2" _
         Or (cell.Value) = "FTV3" _
         Or (cell.Value) = "FTV4" _
         Or (cell.Value) = "FTV5" _
         Or (cell.Value) = "ISTCR" _
         Or (cell.Value) = "CAST" _
         Or (cell.Value) = "Rig" _
         Or (cell.Value) > 50000 And (cell.Value) < 52000 _
         Or (cell.Value) > 55000 And (cell.Value) < 56000 Then
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use brackets (`(`, `)`) to enclose the compound statments

Comment: WHY all those `(cell.Value)` instead of simply `cell.Value` ???

Comment: Seems like it would be better to use a Select Case statement. ..

Comment: How would i write this with a Case statement?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been offline. I will post a suggestion momentarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose the compound statements in extra brackets to explain to the compiler how to order the logical statments...

Try this:

```
If (cell.Value) = "FTV1" _
         Or (cell.Value) = "FTV2" _
         Or (cell.Value) = "FTV3" _
         Or (cell.Value) = "FTV4" _
         Or (cell.Value) = "FTV5" _
         Or (cell.Value) = "ISTCR" _
         Or (cell.Value) = "CAST" _
         Or (cell.Value) = "Rig" _
         Or ((cell.Value) > 50000 And (cell.Value) < 52000) _
         Or ((cell.Value) > 55000 And (cell.Value) < 56000) Then
```

Comment: Assuming cell is a Range, what is its Value when it doesn't work?

Comment: when this is false? any other random thing.

Comment: I plugged *just this* into `Function S_O_Test(ByRef cell As Range)` and got all of the expected results with valid (and invalid) inputs. After the `Then` I had `S_O_Test = 1` and an else returning `S_O_Test = 0`. What isn't working about this answer?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I went through all the boxes and noticed one had #N/A and it wasnt supposed to. That was the error

Answer (score 0):

The `And` conditions are a little tricky without nesting another `Select Case` or `If/Then` inside this statement, but assuming that you're dealing with either string or integer/long values, this should work (tested).

```
Select Case cell.Value
    Case "FTV2", "FTV3", "FTV4", "FTV5", _
         "ISTCR", "CAST", "Rig", _
         50001 To 51999, 55001 To 55999

        'Do your code or call subroutine/function, here.

    Case Else

        'Do other code, or, do nothing, if the above criteria not met.

End Select
```

If you are working with double/decimal data type, then I might need to revise to something like (untested):

```
Select Case cell.Value
    Case "FTV2", "FTV3", "FTV4", "FTV5", _
         "ISTCR", "CAST", "Rig", _
         50000 to 56000

         If (Not IsNumeric(cell.Value)) Or _
            (50000 < cell.Value < 52000) Or _
            (55000 < cell.Value < 56000) Then

            'Do your code or call subroutine/function, here.

         End If
    Case Else

        'Do other code, or, do nothing, if the above criteria not met.

End Select
```